# More than one context type was found in the assembly 'OnlineShoppingStore'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to enable Migrations for my "OnlineShoppingStore" project but running into below error, how do I figure out what the problem is?

> To enable migrations for 'BookService.Models.BookServiceContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName OnlineShoppingStore.Models.EFDbContext.

```
namespace OnlineShoppingStore.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFDbContext()
            : base("EFDbContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: Search your project for another class inheriting the `DbContext`.

Comment: So is it the above error or the below error? Please clear this question up.

Comment: it is the below error